# How to get in SQL oracle nth_value order by one variable with windowing_clause depending on another variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get max, second and third value of column in few lengths of window based on time.

For example, I've got data like this

```
X   | DATE    |   Y  
--------------------
N1  | 2019-01 |  100
N1  | 2019-02 | (null)
N1  | 2019-03 |   30
N1  | 2019-04 |   40
N1  | 2019-05 |   70
N2  | 2019-01 |   80
N2  | 2019-02 |   60
N2  | 2019-03 |   40
N2  | 2019-04 |   50
N2  | 2019-05 |   30
```

I wish to get maximum and second max value of Y over last three months, like this:

```
X   | DATE    | MAX(Y) | SEC(Y)  
-------------------------------
N1  | 2019-01 |  100   | (null)
N1  | 2019-02 |  100   | (null)
N1  | 2019-03 |  100   |   30
N1  | 2019-04 |   40   |   30
N1  | 2019-05 |   70   |   40
N2  | 2019-01 |   80   | (null) 
N2  | 2019-02 |   80   |   60
N2  | 2019-03 |   80   |   60
N2  | 2019-04 |   60   |   50
N2  | 2019-05 |   50   |   40
```

Maximum I can get by

```
select distinct
X, DATE, 
max(y) over (partition by X, DATE order by DATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

What I should to do to get this second (or another nth_value) if the data are in first ordering by DATE value? Adding Y after order by clause doesn't work...
Or, maybe I should reorganize the input data?

Comment: Interesting problem. Several questions for you: (1) For each X, do you have one row per month (in a given interval)? Or can there be gaps, and/or duplicates (two or more rows for the same X and same month)? (2) If you must select the top two from values 90, 90, 30, what are they - 90 and 90, or 90 and 30? (3) What is your Oracle version? This problem may be a perfect application for `match_recognize`, but that requires Oracle 12.1 or higher.

Comment: By the way, your partial solution can't be correct - if you partition by X **and DATE** then each partition consists of exactly one row, not three rows as you may think. DATE should only be in `order by`, not also in `partition by`.

Comment: @mathguy
(1) No, I don't have only one row per month. That was just simple example of problem. And yes, there can be gaps between months, i.e. 2019-01 and next row with 2019-04.
(2)  I would prefer to get solution with 90 and 90 output, but if it will be 90 and 30 it won't be dramatic.
(3) I've got higher version, so I'll look at match_recognize.

Answer (score 1):

One method is two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when y < max_3mon then y end) over
           (partition by X order by dte RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as max2_3mon
from (select t.*, 
              max(y) over (partition by X order by dte RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as max_3mon
      from t 
     ) t
order by x, dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6bfc4e6c3117824063a7eb810dabc9e0) is a db<>fiddle.

This basically calculates the maximum value in the subquery.  It then calculates the maximum *not equal to that value*.  Note that I changed the `partition by` so the query will actually do what you intend.

EDIT:

The above had some wishful programming in it -- namely that the calculated 3 month average was constant.  Oracle makes this a bit tricky, but a lateral join solves the problem:

```
select t.*, max(t.y) over (partition by t.x order by t.dte RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as max_3mon,
       max2.y as max2_3mon
from t left join lateral
     (select distinct t2.y
      from t t2
      where t2.x = t.x and
            t2.dte >= t.dte - interval '2' month and
            t2.dte <= t.dte
      order by t2.y
      offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only
     ) max2
     on 1=1;
```

The db<>fiddle has this correct solution as well.

Comment: I didn't read too closely, but from what I read I don't think this is correct. If we must pick the two highest values from 90, 90, 30, they are 90 and 90 (I believe - it all depends on the exact business problem). This solution will pick 90 and 30.

Comment: @mathguy . . . You should probably ask that on the question to clarify what the OP wants.

Comment: Yup - just did! In any case, suppose he wants the top three values in windows of seven months each, etc. - this approach won't work. (He did mention n-th value a few times in the question.) Better: just one level, using either RANK or DENSE_RANK (depending on the exact requirement), and select the needed rows in outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hmm, it's a good idea but it doesn't work well. As in your solution i.e. X = N2 and DATE = 2019-05 your code give max value of Y equal to 50, and second max value equal to 50 too. It's because in this solution MAX_3MON may be different for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. First I create the sample table (I added one more X to test special cases: for example, when there are two or more values tied for highest, or tied for second-highest, etc.)

In the query, the MATCH_RECOGNIZE part generates the "preceding rows" for each row in the input table. The ROW_NUMBER() computation gives the ranking, and the PIVOT operation at the end lines up the top three values in columns. (I am not convinced of the need to pivot, but this is your problem - YOU know what your business needs are. In any case, pivoting is just icing on the cake, it has nothing to do with the rest of the problem, or of the solution.)

This can be generalized easily to "top-n" - except the last part (pivoting), which can be generalized to "n" easily as well, but "n" needs to be hard-coded, it can't be a user input (bind variable). If you really need to do this pivoted and for variable "n", you will need dynamic SQL (which is best left well alone).

Sample data:

```
create table sample_data (x, dt, y) as
    select 'N1', date '2019-01-13',  100 from dual union all
    select 'N1', date '2019-02-11', null from dual union all
    select 'N1', date '2019-03-01',   30 from dual union all
    select 'N1', date '2019-04-15',   40 from dual union all
    select 'N1', date '2019-05-31',   70 from dual union all
    select 'N2', date '2019-01-01',   80 from dual union all
    select 'N2', date '2019-02-28',   60 from dual union all
    select 'N2', date '2019-03-16',   40 from dual union all
    select 'N2', date '2019-04-15',   50 from dual union all
    select 'N2', date '2019-05-23',   30 from dual union all
    select 'N5', date '2019-03-20',  120 from dual union all
    select 'N5', date '2019-03-24',   85 from dual union all
    select 'N5', date '2019-04-15',  120 from dual union all
    select 'N5', date '2019-04-22',  140 from dual
;
```

Query:

```
with
  mr (x, ref_dt, y, grp, rn) as (
    select x, ref_dt, y, grp, 
           row_number() over (partition by x, grp 
                              order by y desc nulls last)
    from   sample_data
    match_recognize(
      partition by x
      order     by dt desc
      measures  a.dt as ref_dt, match_number() as grp
      all rows per match
      after match skip to next row
      pattern   ( a b* )
      define    b as dt >= add_months(a.dt, -3)
    )
  )
, top_three (x, ref_dt, y, grp, rn) as (
    select x, ref_dt, y, grp, rn
    from   mr
    where  rn <= 3
  )
select x, ref_dt, first, second, third
from   top_three
pivot  (max(y) for rn in (1 as first, 2 as second, 3 as third)) 
order  by x, ref_dt
;
```

Output:

```
X  REF_DT          FIRST     SECOND      THIRD
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
N1 2019-01-13        100                      
N1 2019-02-11        100                      
N1 2019-03-01        100         30           
N1 2019-04-15         40         30           
N1 2019-05-31         70         40         30
N2 2019-01-01         80                      
N2 2019-02-28         80         60           
N2 2019-03-16         80         60         40
N2 2019-04-15         60         50         40
N2 2019-05-23         60         50         40
N5 2019-03-20        120                      
N5 2019-03-24        120         85           
N5 2019-04-15        120        120         85
N5 2019-04-22        140        120        120
```